# Problems in cross compiling glib with autoconf

Tags: cross-compiling, glib, autoconf

I've got a really weird problem in cross compiling glib for android. I run autogen.sh and it gave me this error.

```
configure.ac:88: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DEFINE
  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
  See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/local/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

I am using ndk r10e. And I've installed automake, autoconf,pkg-config,libtool,zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libtool-bin. 
My os is Ubuntu 16.04. I don't think these is much else that I can do except changing to like debian to have a try. Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Try building the latest version of GLib (2.60.0), which uses Meson instead of autotools, so should be a lot easier to cross-compile.